# Using string in whereClause on Android SQLite Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having a problem using a string in a SQLite Update query.

This code is not working .

```
 database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TASKNAME + " = " + strName, null);
```

here strName is a string.

But this code works fine

```
database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " +  id , null);
```

Here id is an integer.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing it like that, you need to add quotation marks around your string:

```
database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TASKNAME + " = \"" + strName + "\"", null);
```

But you should probably really look into parameterized queries (using the `selectionArgs` in [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) like this:

```
database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TASKNAME + " = ?", new String[] { strName })
```

It will make your database safer against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Can you please explain why i should add quotation marks around string?

Comment: + always concate string and for integer it works fine

Comment: The quotes are how sql lite databases identify it's a string. Integers can be taken literally. Read up on sql and it should say something in a section on queries

Comment: Hello, i have been trying to make an update using parameters like that

String whereClause = KEY_FIELD_CODE + “= ?”
String whereArgs[] ={“123456″}

But nothing works just update 0 rows, even if the rows who matches with the field exists. But the result change when i set the update statement like this:

String whereClause = KEY_FIELD_CODE + “= 123456″
String whereArgs[] =null

Does anyone knows why or in which cases we how. and the most important thing is how to fix that.

Note: in this table in particular, im using a FTS3 para implementer full text search..

Thanks